# How to Populate MS Access Main Form By Selecting Any Row from Sub Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Hy Everyone Experts! 
I am trying to populate main form by selecting a single row from sub form in MS Access but it's not working,

Here is Main form!

[image]

In the main form every control is bound to data source.

Here is Sub Form!

[image]

In this form I want to populate row data to the main form by selecting any row form the sub form. As I marked red. When I select it, It should populate in the main form automatically. I tried it by calling reference like this.

> me.ShiftProdRecord2_Query_SubForm = textbox.value

Comment: Is it possible?

Comment: You want to display existing record in the main form? Have you considered using a Split form?

Comment: `its not working` is not a useful description of the problem that you are experiencing ... the only answer possible is `change your program so that it works`

Comment: @June7 bro I did not use split form yet

Comment: @jsotola, the description is written here I am using for to solve it. It not working I know But it will be working?

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Comment: here is a video about the split form. shows how to create one.  ... the video author fails to show what happens when you click on the table portion of the form. ... you can find that out yourself. ... i think that it is exactly what you need.  ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbDV7soewig

Comment: `the description is written here I am using for to solve it` ... you have not said what you are doing to solve your problem ... all you said is `i want this and i want that` ... that is not a description of your work ..... also, you still have not said what is not working for you.

Comment: The single line of code you posted makes no sense. It is definitely NOT setting filter of main form. Simplest solution for you is to use the Split form designer instead of trying to emulate a Split form with a form/subform.

Comment: I am still searching the solution of my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent form and the subform have similar record sources, it would be something like:

```
Me.Parent.Filter = "[ID] = " & Me!ID.Value & ""
Me.Parent.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: I need a code that works when I select any row from the sub form and that automatically populate all the above red marked data in the red marked fields.

Comment: Use the _OnCurrent_ event.